# How to know if my camera is being used by other application in QT/C++?

Tags: qt, camera, window

I am using QCameraInfo::availableCameras to get all available cameras, but it is getting a camera that the meet.google is using at the same time. I would like to alert the user that the camera is currently use by other app. How I could know if those cameras listed are being used by other application in QT?

Comment: I can just guess but have you tried to create a QCamera object with the camera you want to work with and look at it's QCamera::Status? And if you try to start() a QCamera it will return the errorOccured() signal that you can handle

Answer (score 0):

Use the signal `QCamera::statusChanged(QCamera::Status status)` to know about that. Connect this signal to your own slot and check if the status is `QCamera::ActiveStatus`.

slot example:

```
void CameraClass::CheckStatusOfCamera(QCamera::Status status)
{
  if(status == QCamera::ActiveStatus)
     camera.start();
  else
     return;
}
```

Look at this page: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcamera.html#Status-enum